# Problem converting from HTTP request to fetch in Meteor nodejs server using mailgun API to send message

Tags: node.js, meteor, fetch, mailgun

This code, using the meteor request based package HTTP to call the mailgun api has worked for years:

```
HTTP.post(process.env.MAILGUN_API + '/messages', {
    auth: 'api:' + process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
    params
}, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        standardServerError(error, 'while sending email to ' + params.to);
        // throw error;
    }
});
```

Meteor deprecated the HTTP / request package in Meteor 2.0.  So I converted to fetch as follows

```
const response = await fetch(process.env.MAILGUN_API + '/messages', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('api:' + process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY).toString('base64'), 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(params)
});
return response;
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.  Gets a response code of 400 with statusText 'BAD REQUEST'
The params are the same and the deprecated call works.

The answer is that when you call the mailgun api with http, some magic conversions happen behind the scenes.  When using fetch, the magic does not happen.  If I explicitly convert the JSON data to form data before making the mailgun request, then it works as expected.

```
let formData = multipartFormData(params);
const response = fetch(mailgunEndpoint + '/messages', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: _.extend({
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${mailgunUser}:${mailgunAPIKey}`).toString('base64'),
            }, formData.headers),
            body: formData.content
        }).then(response => {
            if (traceSendEmail) {
                console.warn(`{status: ${response.status}, statusText: ${response.statusText}}`);
            }
            return response;
        }).catch(err => {
            standardServerError(err, 'while sending email to ' + params.to);
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: I think your second request auth uses 'Basic' while the first won't and the http package didn't secretly add this so try to remote 'Basic'

Comment: Do you mean remove the word 'Basic' and just use this header?

'Authorization': Buffer.from('api:' + rocess.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY).toString('base64')

When I try that I get 401 - unauthorized.  So I think the auth is working.  But there is something different about how the endpoint is parsing the body when I use fetch I think.,

Comment: Is there a reason you use Buffer anyway? I think the http package does not make the auth String to base64 but maybe let's check the Meteor http package Code to make sure

Comment: I figured out what the problem is.  Meteor http package is doing a lot of magic behind the scenes with the JSON body.  The fetch request is not.  I have to convert the JSON to formdata and include the formdata and its headers in the fetch request and then it works as expected.

Comment: Nice you figured it out by yourself! Please create an answer (that will be useful to others) and accept it, I will upvote.

Comment: Can you post a valid answer? I'm having same issues.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize I had to use the answer button.  I answered it in a comment before.  So there ya go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that when you call the api with http package, some magic conversions happen behind the scenes. When using fetch, the magic does not happen. You must explicitly convert the JSON data to form data before making the api request, then code works as expected.

```
let formData = multipartFormData(params);
    const response = fetch(mailgunEndpoint + '/messages', {
                'method': 'POST',
                'headers': _.extend({
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${mailgunUser}:${mailgunAPIKey}`).toString('base64'),
                }, formData.headers),
                'body': formData.content
            }).then(response => {
                if (traceSendEmail) {
                    console.warn(`{status: ${response.status}, statusText: ${response.statusText}}`);
                }
                return response;
            }).catch(err => {
                standardServerError(err, 'while sending email to ' + params.to);
                return false;
            });
```